# Ansible best practice for a file for every host

Tags: ansible

I need to have a different file for every host, where is the best place to store that?

Is it considered good practice to store it under `files` folder and store the path under `host_vars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing the (expected) contents of the file, I can only provide a partial answer.

A possible solution would be to use a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html), where the contents are rendered from host specific facts, that can, in turn, be harvested automatically at the `setup` step, of provided using custom facts.

If the files are completely different per host, and there is not even a common pattern in how they are composed, you could use the solution you referred in your question, or, storing the files in the `files` directory of your role, use [`with_first_found`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#finding-first-matched-files), and eliminate the need for a specific variable:

```
- template: >
    src={{ item }} 
    dest=/srv/www/error/503.html
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}_503.html"
```

Comment: I am trying to provide a 503 error page for every host so the caching server can have them all stored locally.
I thought of using templates but it didn't look like a good idea to me, since it would be a seperate template for every host.

Comment: That is not correct.

Comment: what's not correct?

Comment: That line of thinking. i.e. assuming that you need a template for each host. What are the pieces of information that are different from host to host that you need on the 503 error page?

Comment: every 503 error page will be completely different. It's not just like swapping out the domain name or something, it will be a completely different html page, different design...etc

Comment: Check my last edit.

Comment: If the page is different for for every website I would consider it as part of the website codebase and manage the 503 error page with the repo for that code.